# Custom ToC for appendices

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, appendices

I would like to create a table of content for the Appendices that produce this result

```
Appendices
   A   First Appendix
   B   Second Appendix
   C   Third Appendix
```

So far I've tried with

```
\appendix
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendices}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\section{First Appendix}
\section{Second Appendix}
\section{Third Appendix}
```

which returns

```
Appendices
   .1   First Appendix
   .2   Second Appendix
   .3   Third Appendix
```

I know it's possible to change the numbering of sections to be alphabetical, but that will also affect all the sections in normal chapters.

Can you find a solution to this?

Comment: It would be nice if there is a MWE(Minimum Working Example)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A change in the counter representation of section (i.e., `\thesection`) only works from the point at which you declare it. So, if the Appendix is the last chapter in your document, then you can adjust `\thesection` at that point with no ill effect to earlier sections:

```
\appendix
\chapter*{Appendices}% If \appendix doesn't insert a \chapter
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendices}% Print Appendix in ToC
\setcounter{section}{0}% Reset numbering for sections
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}% Adjust section printing (from here onward)
\section{First Appendix}
\section{Second Appendix}
\section{Third Appendix}
```

Here is a complete minimal example highlighting the ToC output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A chapter}
\section{First section}
\section{Second section}
\section{Third section}

\appendix
\chapter*{Appendices}% If \appendix doesn't insert a \chapter
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendices}% Print Appendix in ToC
\setcounter{section}{0}% Reset numbering for sections
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}% Adjust section printing (from here onward)
\section{First Appendix}
\section{Second Appendix}
\section{Third Appendix}

\end{document}
```