# Need to Customize Appendix Formatting - both in TOC and Text

Tags: table-of-contents, document-classes, appendices, sweave, appendix

I am using a document class template that is specific to my university's dissertation formatting requirements (the [utexastheses.cls](https://github.com/linguistics/utexas-latex)). It was made by a student a few years ago, and the university does not maintain it. Whoever made the template did not have an appendix (or the appendix formatting has changed since it was made a few years ago), because when I try to make an appendix the formatting does not comply with current formatting requirements. The standard approaches to making an appendix do not work, nor do many of the suggestions I've found on dozens of other questions / posts / blogs / etc.

I am using Rmarkdown and compiling the PDF from a .Rnw file via Sweave.

Below is what is produced by the existing template. I have included two versions, one where the \chapter{} is blank, and one where I use \chapter{Appendices}.

When I use

```
\appendix
\chapter{}
\section{The CATE as a ratio of covariances}
```

I get the following: 
[image: toc1]
[image: text1]

When I use:

```
\appendix
\chapter{Appendices}
\section{The CATE as a ratio of covariances}
```

I get the following:
[image: toc2]
[image: text2]

What I need is to have the TOC to look like:

```
 Appendices                                                     128 
   Appendix A The CATE as a ratio of covariances .............. 128
   Appendix B CATE in Morgan and Winship (2014) ............... 130
   Appendix C Data-Generating Syntax .......................... 132
   Appendix D Estimator Syntax ................................ 136
```

And I need the text to start with just "Appendix A" centered and justified at the top of the page (and so on for each other other appendices). I cannot have "Appendices" as a header - it needs to jump straight to displaying the individual appendix names.

I've pasted what I believe are the relevant bits from the document class template; [the entire template can be found here](https://github.com/linguistics/utexas-latex). If I have not included some important information, please let me know and I will edit my question to include that information.

```
% table of contents configuration
\RequirePackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\RequirePackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents} % default: Contents
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{0.25} % default: 4.5
% Prefix chapter numbers with "Chapter " and add space as needed
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\@chapapp\ }
\newlength{\cftchappresnum@width}
\settowidth{\cftchappresnum@width}{\cftchappresnum}
\addtolength{\cftchapnumwidth}{\cftchappresnum@width}

% chapter heading configuration
% simplified version of the original from report.cls
\def\@makechapterhead#1{{%
  \centering\headingsize
  % print "Chapter N"
  \@chapapp\space\thechapter
  \par\nobreak
  \vskip.25\baselineskip
  \@makeschapterhead{#1}
}}
% star-chapter variation
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{{
  \centering\headingsize
  % prevent page break between following lines at all costs
  \interlinepenalty=10000
  \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
  \vskip\baselineskip
}}

% toc/lot/lof heading configuration
\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{\z@}
\setlength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{.25\baselineskip}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\headingsize\bfseries\hspace*{\fill}}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hspace*{\fill}}
% copy toc to lot
\setlength{\cftbeforelottitleskip}{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}
\setlength{\cftafterlottitleskip}{\cftaftertoctitleskip}
\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\cfttoctitlefont}
\renewcommand{\cftafterlottitle}{\cftaftertoctitle}
% copy toc to lof
\setlength{\cftbeforeloftitleskip}{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}
\setlength{\cftafterloftitleskip}{\cftaftertoctitleskip}
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\cfttoctitlefont}
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\cftaftertoctitle}

\newcommand{\maketableofcontents}{%
  \clearpage
  \tableofcontents
  \clearpage
  \listoftables
  \clearpage
  \listoffigures
  \clearpage\pagenumbering{arabic}
}

\newcommand{\makeappendix}{%
  \appendix
  % ensure that the TOC picks up the redefined value of \@chapapp
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand\protect\cftchappresnum{\@chapapp\ }}
}
```

A brute force solution is fine by me (if one exists). If someone is able to format the template so all future masters/doctoral students can include appendices, I'll gladly pull and branch the template and link to this question in the notes.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Are you using the `utexasthesis` document class? Please provide the code which you used to produce the example.

Comment: We can't try what you have done as you have not provided the `documentclass` you use (plus many othe ommisions such as how you actually try and typeset appendices). I could make at guess at these and try and provide an answer, but if I guess wrong then I will have wasted my time. I am not prepared to do that. --- GOM

Comment: @luki Thank you all for helping me edit my question. I have now included the code that I use to make the included pictures, and I have linked to the utexasthesis.cls that I am using in the case that it's helpful.

Comment: @PeterWilson Thank you as well.

Comment: @CRunyon I tried to download the `utexasthesis.cls` file but all I got was an empty file. Anyway, looking at the instructions it seems that it is not based on the `memoir` class. I am unable to help you. Sorry.

Comment: @PeterWilson. Thank you again for trying. I sincerely appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution I needed here: [Custom ToC for appendices](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172867/custom-toc-for-appendices)

It wasn't exactly what I needed, but close enough that I could figure out what I needed to do with only a few small changes.